# Transition between Activity and fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, transition

I want transition when redirect from Activity to Fragment on a click of button.
I am using below code on click of button in activity but unable to show transition when redirect from Activity to Fragment but the same code is working fine between the Fragment to Fragment redirection.

```
 FragmentTransaction ft = act.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
               ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_from_bottom,
                       R.anim.slide_to_top,
                       R.anim.slide_from_top,
                       R.anim.slide_to_bottom);
               ft.add(R.id.framContainer, new 
AddMealFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

slide_from_bottom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="@integer/slide_animation_duration"/>
</set>
```

slide_to_top.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="-100%p"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="@integer/slide_animation_duration"/>
</set>
```

slide_from_top.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromYDelta="-100%p" android:toYDelta="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="@integer/slide_animation_duration"/>
</set>
```

slide_to_bottom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="100%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="@integer/slide_animation_duration"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Transition Animation between Activity to Fragment**

> *It determines how shared element views are animated from one
>   Activity/Fragment to another during a scene transition.*

This project explains how transition take place in Android from one Activity to another. And Animation by clicking list item with result of showing Details of respective items in another activity. When transition from one activity to another activity we can easily draw a picture between two screens.In Detail Screen we display next consecutive list items and by clicking on respective  list item shows details of the respective item followed by Animation.

Checkout the following Github link:

[Transition Animation](https://github.com/DesignString/TransitionAnimation)